# Examples of non-abelian simply connected nilpotent Lie groups.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, ergodic-theory

I am searching for examples of connected locally compact group $G = N \rtimes H$, where $N$ is a simply connected nilpotent non-abelian Lie group, $H$ is linear reductive and $H$ operates on $N$ without non-trivial fixed points. Please enlighten me.

P.S. I added the ergodic theory tag because I believe such groups are seen there.

Comment: MO crosspost: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317573/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (real or complex) upper triangular group in size $\ge 3$ is a trivial example (with $H$ the diagonal group).

Comment: I believe upper uni-triangular group is nilpotent. but not this.

Comment: Yes: $G$ is the upper triangular group, $N$ is the subgroup of $G$ with diagonal $1$.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand the action of $H$ on $N$.

Comment: The action of $H$ on $N$ is by conjugation. You have a result of 1st year undergraduate, which tells you that if a group $G$ has two subgroups $H,N$, with $N$ normal, $H\cap N=\{1\}$ and $HN=G$, then $G$ is semidirect product $N\rtimes H$ with $H$ acting on $N$ by conjugation.

Comment: If that is the case, doesn't the action fix whole of $N$?

Comment: It stabilizes $N$, which does not means it fixes $N$ (which means fix each point of $N$). In this precise case, no element $\neq 1$ of $N$ is fixed by $H$, because $H$ equals its own centralizer in the group of invertible matrices.